# Make A Checkers Grid Visually?

Tags: java, swing, grid, visualization, awt

Trying to make a Grid [Like this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Checkerboard_pattern.svg/220px-Checkerboard_pattern.svg.png) using java and I'm assuming a 2d Array, I'm eventually going to be making this into checkers game. Making a grid is quite easy but what I am wondering is how can I visually represent this array, so for example the top row second from the left square would be like [0][2] make each square correspond an array index. Any advice would be great, I finished the first java class and I know that this is the first project we get for the next class So! im trying to figure it out, thanks for any help!

Comment: Have a look at my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403738/java-borderlayout-center-getting-the-width-and-height-of-the-jpanel/6403753#6403753

Comment: Top row, second from left = (0,2) does not make sense, you mean third from left. And yes, a 2D Array would work, if Java has them. Otherwise you can roll your own class, using a 1D array (Vector<>?): `1D index = (y * height) + x` or `(x * width) + y`. You could roll that into a method: `myarray.at(3, 4)`. What do you mean by visual representation? Do you want to draw on the screen? On a window?

Comment: No. i mean second from the left, and yes java has 2d arrays.... and yes I wish to draw it on the screen....hence a visual representation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it's an internal convention, it is entirely up to you: simply pick one of the corners of the grid e.g. top-lef, as your *origin*.  (General convention is to use top-left as origin and bottom-right as [x-max][y-max].)

Your model can be anything from a single dimensional raster model or a 2d array, or even nested Lists. Choice of model entirely depends on the use-case and performance requirements.  For your case -- introductory homework -- 2d array is a straightforward and sensible choice.

For drawing to a grid cell @ (i,j), you'll need a method to get the canvas coordinates (x,y) of a given grid cell:

```
/** maps grid cell to coordinates of cell */
public Point getCoordinates(int i, int j);
```

Here you have a couple of choices: should you return the center point e.g. the middle point of a black square, or its relative origin e.g. its top-left coordinates?  Depends on what you are trying to do.  For example, if you are going to be rendering little icons at each cell, the paint api takes the top-left coordinate of the image you are rendering, so in that case, returning the origin is sensible.

You also need to decide if you need to map from a point in the visual grid to your data.  For example, user clicks in the canvas and you need to determine the corresponding data cell.  (You probably don't need this)

```
/** maps point in canvas to a data cell - returned 'point' is (i, j) */
public Point getIndex (int x, int y);
```